# Dijkstra's algorithm cannot deal with negative weights, when do you see negative weights in the real world?

Tags: graph, dijkstra

I can't think of a concrete instance in which you'd have a negative weight. You cannot have a negative distance between two houses, you cannot go back in time. When would you have a graph with a negative edge weight?

I found the Bellman Ford algorithm was originally used to deal with routing in ARPANET, but again, can't imagine where you'd run into a route with a negative weight, it just doesn't seem possible. I could just be thinking too hard about this, what would be a simple example?

Comment: Since w = m * a, you would feel a negative weight if you were under a negative acceleration i.e. you were decelerating. Or have I taken your question too literally...

Comment: Yes if you de-accelerating or the edges represented money you could have a path that is negative. This makes much more sense. All my examples are very physical, then they introduce negative weights and I wasn't thinking outside the box. I guess edges could be money too, so a bunch of paths make money, and then one path loses money.

Comment: I think the money example is good food for thought; but - in that situation - wouldn't you simply remove all of the paths in which you lose money from the graph in consideration before traversing it with Dijkstra's?  Is there any way to have an optimal solution that consists of a path in which you lose money?

Comment: @Dave: Absolutely. A negative-value edge could be the only path to a very highly rewarding subgraph.

Comment: @Jim - ya.  I just figured that out and edited my answer; but you beat me to the punch.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Suppose that walking a distance takes a certain amount of food. But along some paths there is food you can gather, so you might gain food by following those paths.

Answer (score 2):

When doing routing, a negative weight might be assigned to a link to make it the default path. You could use this if you have a primary and a backup line and for whatever reason you don't want to load balance between them.

Comment: I think that is a good point.  In this case though the negative weight doesn't actually represent a negative path weight.  It is more like how sometimes people initialize a value to -1 and then do if(foo >= 0) { bar(); }.  I could see this being used heavily to make a path the default if it were a C implementation.

Comment: Well, when you're dealing with routing protocols, you can set link weights (path weights) to force the protocol to bend to your will. Why you would set a link weight negative, I do not know, but it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Even if there were an example; you could probably normalize it to be all positive.  Any actual representation of a negative weight is relative to some 0.  I guess what I'm saying is that there probably isn't an application of negative weights that can't be done using exclusively positive weights.

EDIT:  After thinking about this a little bit more, I suppose you could have situations where a given path has a negative weight.  In this context; assuming the negative weight is bad, <del>you would have to have a situation where the only possible way to achieve the goal of getting to your desired endpoint, would mean there would have to be at least one point in your graph where you're REQUIRED to take the negative path (as in, no other option is available to reach your goal)</del>.  But I suppose if the graph hasn't been traversed; how would you know it were true?

EDIT (AGAIN): @Jim, I think you're right.  The choke point isn't really relevant.  I guess I was too quick to assume that it was because one question that pops into my mind when introducing negative edges is - if it is possible to traverse the graph without taking ANY negative edge, then what are the negative edges doing there in the first place?  But, this doesn't hold very well, because - outside of hindsight - how would you ever know if a graph could or could not be traversed without going across a negative edge?

Also worth noting, according to the [wikipedia page for Djikstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) :

> Dijkstra's algorithm, conceived by Dutch computer scientist Edsger Dijkstra in 1956 and published in 1959, is a graph search algorithm that solves the single-source shortest path problem for a graph with **nonnegative edge** path costs, producing a shortest path tree. This algorithm is often used in routing and as a subroutine in other graph algorithms.

So, even though this conversation is useful and thought provoking; maybe the title of the question should be "What is the proper algorithm to use for traversing a graph with negative edges?"  Djikstra's algorithm was intended to find the shortest path.  But, if you introduce positive and negative weights, then doesn't the goal change from finding the shortest path to finding the MOST positive - regardless of how many edges are on your chosen path?  And if it does, what is your exit condition?  The only way you could know you've reached the optimal solution would be if you happened across a path that included all positive edges without any negative edges - and wouldn't this scenario only occur by chance?  So - if introducing a situation where there are positive and negative weights changes the goal to be the most positive (or negative depending on how you want to frame it) wouldn't this problem be doomed to O(n!) and therefor be best solved by a decision making algorithm (like alpha/beta) which would produce the best outcome given a restriction on the total amount of edges you're allowed to take?

Comment: Why the restriction that the negative edge is a choke point? Consider starting with 0 points and finding a path through the graph that results in the highest number of points. Each edge can increase or decrease your score. If the weights are constants, then your normalizing approach should work. If the weights can change ... well, that's a different problem altogether, isn't it?

Comment: Substitute "least cost" for "shortest", and it makes more sense.

Comment: By "least cost" do you mean closest to zero?

Comment: Yes. For example, consider the old game Civilization II, where you could move on roads where it cost 1/3 movement point per square or on railroads (if you'd built them), which cost 0 movement points per square. The railroad path might be *longer* (i.e. visit more nodes), but the cost was less than moving any distance on a road.

Comment: For reference, the algorithm for converting negative edge weights into positive ones is part of Johnson's Algorithm; it requires a single-source shortest path computation supporting negative edge weights as a preprocessing step, though.  You use it to compute all-pairs shortest paths so you can use Dijkstra's Algorithm for most of the sources.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you might get negative weights where you've already got a system with non-negative weights and a path comes along that is cheaper than all existing paths, and for some reason it's expensive to reweight the network.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to find the quickest way to swim across a series of linked pools in a water park, and it has flumes.

Comment: Flumes ... THAT GO BACKWARDS THROUGH TIME!